# How to update only subset of all fields in Spring JPA repository?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I would like to update one field in `User` domain model and I don't want to process whole instance of domain model.

Data for update are represented in `UserEncryptionData` domain model class. `BaseEntity` (parent class) holds primary key for `User` entity - so JPA has all information (IMHO) needed to process the update.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserEncryptionData extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "salt", unique = true)
    @JsonProperty("salt")
    private String salt;

    public String getSalt() {
        return salt;
    }

    public void setSalt(String salt) {
        this.salt = salt;
    }
}
```

In `UserRepository` I would like to update these data:

```
public interface UserRepository extends BaseRepository<User, UUID> {    
   User update(UserEncryptionData encryptionData);    
// the rest omitted...    
}
```

but Spring complains:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property update found for type User!

Is this way possible to update only subset of domain model fields or do I have to process whole `User` entity?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the save method on `UserEncryptionData` object after obtaining it from the database, and modified the fields you need to update and Spring will do the job.

```
UserEncryptionData user = userRepository.findById("id");

user.setSalt("updated salt");

user.save();
```

But if you want only to update one field you have to write your own update query using `@Modifying` and `@Query` annotations:

```
@Modifying
@Query("update UserEncryptionData u set u.salt = :salt where u.id = :id")
int setUserById(@Param("salt") String salt, @Param("id") Long id);
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries